# Directory error when trying to make a second command handler in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm a beginner and have no clue what is going on. I'm pretty sure I'm just formatting the directory wrong. I created a command handler, and in one of those executables, am trying to implement a second command handler. I copied the original, and formatted it for this directory. When I run the program I get this: **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './duels'**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const { prefix, token } = require('../config.json');


client.duels = new Discord.Collection();

const duelFiles = fs.readdirSync('./duels').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

for (const file of duelFiles) {
    const command = require(`./duels/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(duel.name,duel);
}

module.exports = {
    name: 'duel',
    description: 'fight your friends!',
        execute(message,args) {

            try{

                if (args[0].startsWith('<@')){
                    const opponent = args[0];
                    const attacker = message.author.username;
                    const duel = args[1];

                    if(!client.duels.has(duel)) {
                        message.reply(`bro that duel type doesn't exist \n\`please use this format: ${prefix}duel @person [duel type]\` \nfor a list of duels, type ${prefix}duelhelp`)
                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        client.duels.get(duel).execute(message,args);
                    } catch (error) {
                          console.error(error);
                          message.reply(`bro that duel type doesn't exist`)
                    }

                } else {message.reply(`you gotta mention a person with @ \n\`please use this format: ${prefix}duel @person [duel type]\``)}

            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                message.reply(`yeah ok, duel. what does that mean?? \n\`please use this format: ${prefix}duel @person [duel type]\``)
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: Do you have a separate file called duels.js?

Comment: this is my file system https://imgur.com/a/xTlFUSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative filepaths work differently for different parts of node.js. `require` will interpret them relative to the *current file*, i.e. what file actually contains the `require` statement. But file i/o is relative to the current working directory (CWD) - this will be where you executed the program from.

With that in mind, you'll want to replace this:

```
fs.readdirSync('./duels')
```

with this:

```
fs.readdirSync('./commands/duels')
```

Comment: @lemon As stated in the answer, `require` interprets relative paths relative to the file containing the `require` statement. It looks like you changed your code to read require(\`./commands/duels/${file}\`) when it should still be require(\`./duels/${file}\`)

Comment: got it. How can I acquire config.json in the nested folder? I'm not sure how to dictate two folders out.

Comment: @lemon use `..` (two dots) to go up one folder, as you've done in your snippet above. You can do this multiple times, e.g. `require('../../config.json')`

Comment: Thank you very much.